# django connection.cursor() get stuck when used within daemon

Tags: mysql, django, database-connection, innodb

I have a daemon which has some of the queries written using connection.cursor()

```
>> from django.db import models, connection
>> cursor = connection.cursor()
>> cursor.execute("some sql query")
```

Except within daemons this method works perfectly fine. But in daemon whenever connection.cursor() is called it gets stuck. Also it stops printing anything via logger (till daemon is restarted). Only the queries used via django work fine after everything has stuck.

Earlier this code use to work fine when i was using postgres db. So I am doubting it is something related to mysql inodb combination.

Please suggest how can i make this work using connection.cursor()??

Comment: I had some similar issues using MySQL, and one solution was to close every cursor after every query. It was due to a bug in the support of MySQL for python. Maybe it can help you ;)

Comment: well after more analysis i found out that there were 2 issues...1) the query via cursor.execute() was running but not getting updated as commit was not being called. 2) connection.cursor() is closing my existing logger and placing a socket connection at that place. It seems there is issue with logger mysql and file decriptor. Not sure yet.
Is there any way by which i can my set django 1.3 settings with mysql Innodb to autocommit true??